# Python canopy can't import "xlrd" package in editor (not in Ipython)

Tags: python, xlrd, canopy

I installed `xlrd` package using `Canopy package manager (Academic edition)` in `Windows 8.1`. When I use this code :

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
```

I have this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name open_workbook
```

Whem alternatively use this code :

```
from xlrd import * #There isn't any returned error for this specific line
```

and use `open_workbook()` as a function, there isn't any defined function with this name.
What is the problem?

**PS.**
In Ipyhton, `import xlrd as xx` will word (xx. after that). But in editor it doesn't work. `from xlrd import *` will work to in python ( `open_workbook()` after that ).

When I use `import xlrd as my_c` and run it in editor, `my_c.` with dot notation works in Iphyton but doesn't work in editor! When i insert `my_c` in editor and press tab, I have `my_c.xx`.

Comment: What is the output from import xlrd; xlrd.__file__ ?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason would be that you've somehow put another module named xlrd on your sys.path.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Actually the first sentence provides the likely answer. The second sentence asks a question which will help them test that answer. I've separated them into a comment and an answer, which won't help the OP but if it makes you happy, so be it.